# How do I add extra params via routes for controllers or views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

I know in rails routes that I can do something like `get 'books/*section/:title', to: 'books#show'` to have `params[:title]` available in controller or views.

But I can't find something to get a fixed extra parameter available. Like, I would always get something like `params[:preview] = true` always on certain parameters based on the routes.

I know I could always do something like:

```
def new
  params.merge!({preview: true})
end
```

but I was wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `defaults`

```
get 'books/*section/:title', to: 'books#show', defaults: {preview: true}
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Comment: O there it is! Why didn't I see that. I was reading up on that as well but went straight to route globbing and wildcards.

Comment: I used something like `get 'photos/:id', to: 'photos#show', defaults: { format: 'jpg' }` in my routes to make it work.